# Using ClickOnce getting two instances of the program after update

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, clickonce

I've started getting `ClickOnce` setup and using the code below after calling `Application.Restart();` I end up with two instances of the application (the newly updated one and the previous version).

```
    private static void CheckForUpdate() {
            ApplicationDeployment updateCheck = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
            UpdateCheckInfo info = updateCheck.CheckForDetailedUpdate();
            if(info.UpdateAvailable) {
                updateCheck.Update();
                MessageBox.Show( "The application has been upgraded, and will now restart." );
                Application.Restart();
            }
    }//this has try/catch but didn't think it would be relevant 
     //since no exception is being thrown
```

This is my first time using click once and while I'm amazed at the simplicity of it I wasn't quite sure WHERE to put the manual check (I don't want the users to have a choice or see the ugly update window).

I've placed it both in my `MainForm.cs` and my `Program.cs` with the same results for both.  I'm including my `Main()` just in case it's relevant.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    CheckForUpdate();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault( false );
    Application.Run( new MainForm() );
}
```

Comment: When ever I use Click One I rely on the app detecting if there is a newer version. But `since you dont want users to see the window or have a choice` I found this for you [Suppressing the Launching Application Window of ClickOnce](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/cd991579-bf49-4bac-b095-e1f5932a47a0/). If it goes well pls post your results!

Comment: The code I listed already does this with a couple exceptions.  It is an ASync check (I'm not worried about it delaying startup as everything is internal so it isn't even noticeable) and the posted code from that forum also sleeps the thread for 1.5 second which didn't change what was happening for me...sadly

Comment: `Its an ASync method` - that your trying to use to launch a new instance of the program after its updated itself? If so IMHO its better to rely on Click Once technology.

Comment: I am relying on ClickOnce I'm just launching it manually as opposed to having the ClickOnce program launch the check.  The benefit to doing so manually being that you don't see that ugly window.  What I was saying is the code that you linked to is performing the check in an ASync fasion so that the program can go ahead an launch...if it finds an update the ASync.finished method performs the restart/etc...  I'm not concerned with a slight 1-2 second delay (in testing it's been around .5 sec) in startup and if it finds an update then I want it to delay starting incase it's required update.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I was able to figure out a solution based on your link I have answered the question with a variant of the code that I finished up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  The link provided by Jeremy Thompson gave me some ideas...mainly the delay, but without implementing a sleeping thread (since in the instance of that code simply delayed the start of the app).

What I ended up doing was implementing an optional Parameter in my default constructor that started a timer (set for 1.5 seconds, but could be modified as needed if app needed more startup time).  When the Timer's `Tick` event fired THAT'S when I called `Application.Restart()`.  My app has some Active Directory calls and Database Calls to get itself setup like it should and I'm guessing this is what caused the unexpected results, but I'm not sure.

NEW CONSTRUCTOR...

```
public MainForm(bool WasUpdated = false) {
    InitializeComponent();
    if(!WasUpdated) {
        instance = this;
        Icon = DesktopInterface.MainForm.Properties.Resources.favicon;
        tabPages = DesktopInterface.MainForm.Setup.TabSetup.GetTabs();
        foreach(var page in tabPages) {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add( page );
        }
    } else {
        restartTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

and my modified `Program.cs`

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    CheckForUpdate();
    SetAddRemoveProgramsIcon();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault( false );
    Application.Run( new MainForm(WasUpdated) );
}
//WasUpdated is a class level variable that gets set inside of the CheckForUpdate method
```

Full `CheckForUpdate()` Method....

```
private static void CheckForUpdate() {
            try {
                ApplicationDeployment updateCheck = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
                UpdateCheckInfo info = updateCheck.CheckForDetailedUpdate();
                if(info.UpdateAvailable) {
                    updateCheck.Update();
                    WasUpdated = true;
                    MessageBox.Show( "The application has been upgraded, and will now restart." );
                }
            } catch(DeploymentDownloadException ex) {
                MessageBox.Show( "Automatic Update Failed.  Error: " + ex );
            } catch(InvalidDeploymentException ex) {
                MessageBox.Show( "Automatic Update Failed.  Error: " + ex );
            } catch(DeploymentException ex) {
                MessageBox.Show( "Automatic Update Failed.  Error: " + ex );
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show( "Automatic Update Failed.  Error: " + ex );
            }
        }
```

What I'll end up doing after posting this is switching the `CheckForUpdate()` to have a return value and then just passing that to the `MainForm` Constructor instead of having a class level flag in `Program.cs`

Comment: I am still confused as to how to stop two instances from loading after it is updated. Could you please explain more clearly? What in the default `InstallUpdateSyncWithInfo` method causes two instances to load? The title of this post is a bit misleading. I came to this page looking to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `InstallUpdateSyncWithInfo` method is.  Also, I no longer have access to the code, but if your code is launching two instances then close the "old" one and since it's launching a second then it should live, without some code I'm not sure how to help though.